# div css height 100% not working

Tags: html, css, height

I don't know why this doesnt work, but I want the div to go with the scroll like the text does. Here is the jsfiddle example. Also I've seen that sometimes the body will only have the height of the browser and if I scroll, the body won't continue.

http://jsfiddle.net/KfjGU/844/

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id=fullheight>
        Lorem Ipsum     Appareat eleifend consequat ut per, adipisci praesent pro no, quot nostrum ne cum. Legimus vulputate vix ex, odio aliquam ut has, eu quo debet solet consectetuer. Natum populo feugiat pro at. Tritani nusquam est ei, ut sed vidit lorem quaerendum. His semper euismod adipiscing in, maiorum detracto legendos cu duo, tation commodo mediocrem his ad. Usu ad error numquam tractatos.
<P> 
Ne duo epicuri voluptua petentium, enim adipisci ut nec, in sea agam lorem admodum. Ut sed verterem consequuntur, ea tollit mnesarchum mel. Commodo denique an sed, qui ei erant possit. In cum virtute commune eloquentiam, nec libris nominati et, percipit delicata eum an.
<P>
Nostro omittantur et eos, has diceret nominavi pertinax at, ei mel indoctum explicari. An quo veniam facete, an sit ignota definiebas. At molestiae conclusionemque eum, eos nostro aliquam id. Ius reque tritani quaestio ne.
<p>
Appareat eleifend consequat ut per, adipisci praesent pro no, quot nostrum ne cum. Legimus vulputate vix ex, odio aliquam ut has, eu quo debet solet consectetuer. Natum populo feugiat pro at. Tritani nusquam est ei, ut sed vidit lorem quaerendum. His semper euismod adipiscing in, maiorum detracto legendos cu duo, tation commodo mediocrem his ad. Usu ad error numquam tractatos.
<P> 
Ne duo epicuri voluptua petentium, enim adipisci ut nec, in sea agam lorem admodum. Ut sed verterem consequuntur, ea tollit mnesarchum mel. Commodo denique an sed, qui ei erant possit. In cum virtute commune eloquentiam, nec libris nominati et, percipit delicata eum an.
<P>
Nostro omittantur et eos, has diceret nominavi pertinax at, ei mel indoctum explicari. An quo veniam facete, an sit ignota definiebas. At molestiae conclusionemque eum, eos nostro aliquam id. Ius reque tritani quaestio ne.   
    </div>
</body>
</html>


html, body, #fullheight {
min-height: 100% !important;
height: 100%;
}
body {
background: red;
}
#fullheight {
width: 250px;
background: blue; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
html, body, #fullheight {
    min-height: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
}
```

you have repeated height attribute!, just remove !important and height attribute.
then your code will be:

```
html, body, #fullheight {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `height: inherit;` 
You have **height:100% but 100% of what?**

That's why it is not working.
[JS FIDDLE USING height:inherit;](http://jsfiddle.net/KfjGU/845/)

**CHECK SNIPPET**

```css
html, body, #fullheight {
    
    height: inherit;
}
body {
  background: red;
}
#fullheight {
    width: 250px;
    background: blue;
      
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fullheight">
           <p> Lorem Ipsum     Appareat eleifend consequat ut per, adipisci praesent pro no, quot nostrum ne cum. Legimus vulputate vix ex, odio aliquam ut has, eu quo debet solet consectetuer. Natum populo feugiat pro at. Tritani nusquam est ei, ut sed vidit lorem quaerendum. His semper euismod adipiscing in, maiorum detracto legendos cu duo, tation commodo mediocrem his ad. Usu ad error numquam tractatos.</p>
<p> 
Ne duo epicuri voluptua petentium, enim adipisci ut nec, in sea agam lorem admodum. Ut sed verterem consequuntur, ea tollit mnesarchum mel. Commodo denique an sed, qui ei erant possit. In cum virtute commune eloquentiam, nec libris nominati et, percipit delicata eum an.</p>
<p>
Nostro omittantur et eos, has diceret nominavi pertinax at, ei mel indoctum explicari. An quo veniam facete, an sit ignota definiebas. At molestiae conclusionemque eum, eos nostro aliquam id. Ius reque tritani quaestio ne.</p>
<p>
Appareat eleifend consequat ut per, adipisci praesent pro no, quot nostrum ne cum. Legimus vulputate vix ex, odio aliquam ut has, eu quo debet solet consectetuer. Natum populo feugiat pro at. Tritani nusquam est ei, ut sed vidit lorem quaerendum. His semper euismod adipiscing in, maiorum detracto legendos cu duo, tation commodo mediocrem his ad. Usu ad error numquam tractatos.</p>
<P> 
Ne duo epicuri voluptua petentium, enim adipisci ut nec, in sea agam lorem admodum. Ut sed verterem consequuntur, ea tollit mnesarchum mel. Commodo denique an sed, qui ei erant possit. In cum virtute commune eloquentiam, nec libris nominati et, percipit delicata eum an.</P>
<P>
Nostro omittantur et eos, has diceret nominavi pertinax at, ei mel indoctum explicari. An quo veniam facete, an sit ignota definiebas. At molestiae conclusionemque eum, eos nostro aliquam id. Ius reque tritani quaestio ne. </P> 
        </div>
         
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the height to 100% sets the div to 100% of the height of your window. If you remove the height value, the div will be the full height of the parent div.

```
html, body, #fullheight {
    min-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KfjGU/846/

Comment: @OkeTega I just left that in from before, in hindsight I should have made it a little better.

Answer (score 0):

your html should look like this.

1. put closing tag of p

2.put id in side double Quot.

```
<div id="fullheight">
               <p>

               Lorem Ipsum     Appareat eleifend consequat ut per, adipisci praesent pro no, quot nostrum ne cum. Legimus vulputate vix ex, odio aliquam ut has, eu quo debet solet consectetuer. Natum populo feugiat pro at. Tritani nusquam est ei, ut sed vidit lorem quaerendum. His semper euismod adipiscing in, maiorum detracto legendos cu duo, tation commodo mediocrem his ad. Usu ad error numquam tractatos.</p>
    <P> 
    Ne duo epicuri voluptua petentium, enim adipisci ut nec, in sea agam lorem admodum. Ut sed verterem consequuntur, ea tollit mnesarchum mel. Commodo denique an sed, qui ei erant possit. In cum virtute commune eloquentiam, nec libris nominati et, percipit delicata eum an.</P>
    <P>
    Nostro omittantur et eos, has diceret nominavi pertinax at, ei mel indoctum explicari. An quo veniam facete, an sit ignota definiebas. At molestiae conclusionemque eum, eos nostro aliquam id. Ius reque tritani quaestio ne.</P>
    <p>
    Appareat eleifend consequat ut per, adipisci praesent pro no, quot nostrum ne cum. Legimus vulputate vix ex, odio aliquam ut has, eu quo debet solet consectetuer. Natum populo feugiat pro at. Tritani nusquam est ei, ut sed vidit lorem quaerendum. His semper euismod adipiscing in, maiorum detracto legendos cu duo, tation commodo mediocrem his ad. Usu ad error numquam tractatos.</p>
    <P> 
    Ne duo epicuri voluptua petentium, enim adipisci ut nec, in sea agam lorem admodum. Ut sed verterem consequuntur, ea tollit mnesarchum mel. Commodo denique an sed, qui ei erant possit. In cum virtute commune eloquentiam, nec libris nominati et, percipit delicata eum an.</P>
    <P>
    Nostro omittantur et eos, has diceret nominavi pertinax at, ei mel indoctum explicari. An quo veniam facete, an sit ignota definiebas. At molestiae conclusionemque eum, eos nostro aliquam id. Ius reque tritani quaestio ne. </P>  
            </div>
```

and Css should look like this.

```
body {
  background: red;
}
#fullheight {
    width: 250px;
    background: blue; 
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body, #fullheight {
min-height:10%;
display: table;
}
body {
background: red;
}   
#fullheight {
width: 250px;
background: blue; 
}



listen , height:100% is not realy true! you can use height:auto or use px em
```